# still being charged for CGP Composer 2 after deletion

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer

I had Composer 2 instance and deleted it, but for some reason still being charged a few bucks for Cloud Composer Compute mCPUs and Cloud Composer Compute Memory. Could those be delayed charges or something? I thought it might be, but it has been a couple of days and i am still seeing charges. Cloud Composer Environment Fee is not being charged after deletion, it is only CPU and Memory.

[image]

Tried contacting support but no reply yet.
Anyone had the same situation?
Thanks!

Comment: You have a compute engine instance running somewhere. Double check under Compute Engine. Add tags to resources so that you know which resources you are being charged for.

Comment: @JohnHanley thank you for your answer. Thats the thing, I dont have any VMs running. As you can see from the SKU, charges are related to the Composer VM instances that were deleted after I deleted the environment.

Comment: Then my recommendation is to open a **free** billing support request. There might be an issue that requires Google to investigate.

Comment: @Daria as mentioned by *@Jhon* this can happen only when you don't delete the compute engine disks. I hope that you have cleaned up the environment as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/run-apache-airflow-dag). Also if you have already contacted [Billing Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing) , they must have responded to you by now.You can share the update from them here.

Comment: @SayanBhattacharya thank you so much! Indeed i forgot to delete the persistent disk. I didnt know that deleting environment does not delete its persistent disk.

Answer (score 2):

I forgot to delete the persistent disk. Deleting the Cloud Composer environment does not delete its persistent disk.
https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/delete-environments